# How to view the details of any specific item from Database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I am creating a program which shows a list of product to user and when a user click on any specific product, it opens the product and user can view the details of that specific product. I have written the following code,but it is not showing any output. if I see the address bar it looks like its working fine, but at browser it is neither showing any output nor any error.

> Address Bar localhost/cms/single_product.php?product_id=25

Kindly guide me.

Thanks

```
<?php
session_start();
//$id= $_SESSION['id'];
$id= $_GET['product_id'];

    include 'connect.php';


        $query= "select * from products, product_description where products.product_id=$id 
                    and product_description.product_id=$id";


        echo "<a href='update_single_product.php?product_id=$id' > Update Product</a>";

            if ($query_run=mysql_query($query))
                {
                    $fetch=     mysql_fetch_array($query_run);



                    //print_r ( $fetch['product_id']);      

                    echo $fetch['name'];
                    echo $fetch['description'];
                    echo $fetch['item_no'];
                    echo $fetch['recipient'];       


                }

            else
                {

                echo mysql_error();
                        }



?>
```

Comment: try this: `echo "<a href=\"update_single_product.php?product_id=".$id."\" > Update Product</a>"` And it looks like the same should be done for `$query=`

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have tried it but still the same result.

Comment: Have tried this?:  `$query= "select * from products, product_description where products.product_id=".$id." 
                    and product_description.product_id=".$id.";`

Comment: @taha-kirmani Run the query in PhpMyadmin and check the result.

Comment: Thinks there is a mistake in your query. @taha-kirmani

Comment: Oh!! I got the problem. 'PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION' has very limited data and 'PRODUCT' table is huge. When I check a record whose information is not given in 'PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION' table it doesn't give me any data. Now i am using LEFT Join and its working perfectly fine:) Thank You So Much !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT products.*,product_description.* FROM products
INNER JOIN product_description
ON (products.product_id=$id AND product_description.product_id=$id)
this will work definitely
```